# Adding CSS on hapi.js is not woking

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, hapi.js

Using **inert** plugin I tried to add the public folder where I kept my css, js files. But on my **views** folder I can't access them. I'm using handlebars. Even if I keep only the **style.css** on the **views** folder still **html** can't access that style file.

This is my folder structure:

```
app.js
public
   css
     style.css
 views
     home.html
 routes
     user.js
```

**App.js**

```
const server = hapi.server({
   port: Number(process.argv[2] || 3000),
});
const init = async () => {

   await server.register(vision);
   await server.register(inert);
   server.views({
        engines: {
            html: handlebars
        },
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
        relativeTo: path.join(__dirname, 'public')

    });

}
```

I tried to add relative path also on the server like this :

```
const server = hapi.server({
   port: Number(process.argv[2] || 3000),
   routes: {
        files: {
            relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'public')
       }
   }
});
```

But in vain.

**Home.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Login page</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
 </head>
   <body>
        <h2> Welcome </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
background: #456;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a route to serve the content of your public folder.

This can be done with the [Directory Handler](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files?lang=en_US):

```js
const init = async () => {
    await server.register(vision);
    await server.register(inert);

    server.views(...)

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/public/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This will create a route that will serve any content in the `public` directory, so your css will be accessible via http://localhost:3000/public/css/style.css.

This mean you don't have to access the stylesheet with a relative path and can use an absolute path in your *home.html*:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: it worked thanks. But what if instead of keeping this route on  **app.js** file, i want to keep it on **routes** folder to **user.js** file? for this, do i have to change my html link to `href="../public/css/style.css"`? I tried but it didn't work. I've modified my folder structure. Please do have a look

Comment: The route that serve static content mostly don't have a relation with your template files, in fact the `routes.files.relativeTo` directive only tell hapi to use the path you provide so when calling `h.view` in a route handler, the path will resolve from `relativeTo` so it's only usefull inside the server, not from the client (eg: the views). What does you user.js file do ?

Comment: `user.js` contains my all server.routes i.e `return h.view('home') files`. I exported them to use on `app.js`. Well, I figured it out by changing the directory path to `path.join(__dirname, ../'public')`